# OutputCache and A potentially dangerous Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I have enabled OutputCache, and are using the following attributes:

```
[OutputCache]
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> [HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous
>   Request.QueryString value was detected from the client
>   (pool="lger<br />/for...").]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String
>   collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection) +11933898
>   System.Web.HttpValueCollection.EnsureKeyValidated(String key)
>   +11932776    System.Web.HttpValueCollection.Get(String name) +23    System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.CreateOutputCachedItemKey(String
>   path, HttpVerb verb, HttpContext context, CachedVary cachedVary) +880 
>   System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs
>   eventArgs) +803
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +142    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +92

Why is this happening? I don't get why the OutputCachedItemKey needs to validated? Any way how to disable this?

**Note that it only goes wrong with enabling the OutputCache**.

Without everything works fine.

**Update**
It seems really easy reproduciable:

1. Start new ASP.NET Project with ASP.NET MVC template (4.5.2)
2. Add `[OutputCache( Duration = 1)]`
3. run http://localhost:(port)/?test=%3Cscript%3E

Result:
Potentially dangerous request, despite that you do anything with this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because the client passed in `pool="lger<br />` to the Query String.  Notice the HTML character `<br />`, this can be considered an XSS attack and the framework handles this for you by default.

You want to keep this security enabled, imagine if the client passed up

```
"<script type='javascript'>//Nasty code</script>"
```

As part of the query string, it could be reflected or persisted to the users of your system.

You can also add the MVC attribute [`AllowHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
public class Model
{
   [AllowHtml]
   public string Pool { get; set; }
}
```

However, if you really want to disable Request Validation [(Not recommended)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx) then you can do so via the `web.config`

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: the `[AllowHtml]` usually goes on modal properties not on controllers. _Allows a request to include HTML markup during model binding by skipping request validation for the property._

Comment: Hi @DarrenDavies, thanks for your quick answer. The thing is my action is working fine (I'm not reading the value). It's the OutputCache that doesn't seem to be able to handle it - see the StackTrace.

Comment: @DirkBoer - I've read it and it looks like it throws at this point `System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString` not at the OutputCache level.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But it looks like that ValidateString is being by the OutputCacheModule (through Get and EnsureKeyValidated)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to be using the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for reference.

> By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework checks requests during model
>   binding to determine whether they contain potentially dangerous
>   content as HTML markup. If HTML is detected, model binding throws an
>   error. If a property is marked with the AllowHtmlAttribute attribute,
>   the ASP.NET MVC framework skips validation for that property during
>   model binding.

Comment: Hi @zgood, thanks for your quick answer. The thing is my action is working fine (I'm not reading the value). It's the OutputCache that doesn't seem to be able to handle it - see the included StackTrace.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that `OutputCachedItemKey` tries to create a unique identifier for the request which includes parameter information. Doing this calls `ValidateString` which leads to the exception for values that are considered dangerous.

That said, I don't have a real solution either. However, if the goal is to disable caching for the action entirely this attribute should work

`[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByContentEncoding = null, VaryByCustom = null, VaryByHeader = null, VaryByParam = null)]`